# Why does this code in a stored procedure produce an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If the login does NOT exist this code works.
If the login DOES exist this code still works (it's ignored as it should be) but produces an error.

> Error: Login already exists

```
Declare @User carchar(50)
Declare @sqlstmt varchar(200)

set @User = quotename('JSmith')
    
if not exists (select @User from sys.syslogins where name = @User and isntuser = 1)
begin
    set @sqlstmt='CREATE LOGIN '+ @User +' FROM WINDOWS'
    Exec (@sqlstmt)
end
```

I've read where the code is compiled before the IF statement executes which would explain the error. I just don't know how to work around this.

Comment: `Login already exists` is *not* a compile error -- that can only happen when actually executing the `CREATE LOGIN` statement, which suggests your `IF` isn't checking things like you expect them to. Alternatively, you may have stray statements after what you think is the procedure body (which is not contained in `BEGIN ... END` but rather whatever the entire batch is), but that we can't tell from just this code.

Comment: `carchar`? And always use `nvarchar(max)` for your dynamic statement

Comment: And what is the `isntuser` column? Aren't you are interested in logins who are users? Could the filter be hiding a user of the same name?

Comment: Thank you David but the issue still exists. The code works perfectly outside of the stored procedure. But when executed from within the sproc it produces the following error and thus fails. Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Windows NT user or group '[UIREHAB\lsmith]' not found. Check the name again.

Answer (score 2):

The login name won't be delimited by '[]' in the system views, so your code will not find the login if it exists.

You only use QUOTENAME when adding the identifier to dynamic SQL.  And `sys.server_principals` is the newer view for this, so:

```
declare @User nvarchar(200) = N'YourServerOrDomain\YourUserName'
    
if not exists (select * from sys.server_principals where name = @User and type = 'U')
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE LOGIN '+ quotename(@User) +' FROM WINDOWS'
    --print @sqlstmt
    exec (@sql)
end
```

Comment: Problem resolved. Stupid syntax error on my part. Thanks to all for your help!